# AfterEffects , Create floating objects

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I want to create a floating objects when time freezes ...
Zach king created a video that throw popcorn in the air , then time freeze and then camera moves around ... Search : 'Zachking Popcorn' then see the floating popcorns for more info that what I exactly saying

Did i need a special camera to create floating objects and then move camera ?
Or i need skills to create this using aftereffects and how ...?

Comment: I don't know, but there is a graphics.stackexchange,com   like graphicsdesign.stackexchange or computergraphics.stackexchange.  that you could try asking on.. it might be a good question to  try there..

Comment: Ok thanks , sorry for wrong section that i asked ...

Comment: I don't know if it's the wrong section, maybe.